# Linear transformations that preserve a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space (say over $Z_2$) and let $U$ be a subspace of dimension $k$. I was wondering if there is a way to characterize full-rank $n\times n$ linear transformations $A$ that preserve the subspace; i.e., for any $v\in U$ it also holds that $Av\in U$.

The identity matrix definitely preserves the subspace, but are there more?

Comment: Take a basis $v_1,v_2, \dots, v_k$ of $U$ and extend it to a basis $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ of $V$. The coefficients of $v_{k+1},v_{k+2},\dots,v_n$ in $Av_1, Av_2, \dots, Av_k$ must all be zero.

Comment: @MichaelBiro Thanks! This definitely takes me closer, but still I cannot see if there are more such matrices. So I have that for all $1\le i\le k$ it holds that $Av_i=\sum_{1\le j\le k}b_jv_j$ but how do I actually find such an $A$?

Comment: If $S$ is the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to the basis constructed by @MichaelBiro, then any matrix of the form $A = S^{-1}TS$ will work, where $T$ is of the form $\begin{pmatrix}T_{11} &  T_{12} \\ 0 & T_{22}\end{pmatrix}$ and is invertible. Here, $T_{11}$ is $k\times k$, $T_{12}$ is $k \times (n-k)$, and $T_{22}$ is $(n-k) \times (n-k)$.

Comment: Thanks @Bungo! Indeed if we have that $e_i = Sv_i$ for all $1\le i \le k$, then $Av_i = S^{-1}TSv_i = S^{-1}Te_i=S^{-1}v$ where in $v$ only the first $k$ entries can be non-zero and thus $v=\sum_{1\le j\le k}b_je_j$. Therefore, $Av_i=\sum_{1\le j\le k}b_jS^{-1}e_j = \sum_{1\le j\le k}b_jv_j$. Do you think that we can claim that the total number of such matrices is just the total number of different $T$'s?

Comment: @Bungo I would be also curious about how you came up with this answer. :)

Comment: are you familiar with the notion of (internal) direct sums of vector spaces? because if you are, then there is a nice way of formulating the statement that a linear map leave a subspace invariant. (It's pretty much like what bungo said, regarding one of the blocks being zero)

Comment: @hedgehog Your original question asks for $A$ to be full rank, i.e. invertible. This will be true if and only if $T$ is invertible, which is true if and only if $T_{11}$ and $T_{22}$ are invertible. $T_{12}$ can be anything. So if you can count the number of invertible $k \times k$ and $(n-k) \times (n-k)$ matrices, it should be easy to count the total number of possible $T$ matrices. And there's a one-to-one correspondence between $T$ matrices of this form and matrices $A$ that satisfy your requirement.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I am not very familiar but I just realized that "subspace invariant" is the proper term and there is plenty of information out there that probably explains this nice connection. Thank you!

Comment: Also, many thanks again @Bungo I believe that your comments actually answer my question. So I should be able to dig into more details and write an answer.